# Greasemonkey finding text issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm currently using this script (below) to find a specific word and alert me however action is ajax meaning the page doesn't refresh. It's wrapped in a span;

`<span id="res">Use your arrow keys to begin</span>`

this span shows the result after clicking the arrows. The script works but since the span updates via ajax it can't find the new results how can I work around this?

```
interval = setInterval(function() {                         
if (/Shiny/i.test (document.body.innerHTML)){
   clearInterval(interval)
   alert ("Found it!");
 }
}, Math.random()*300+500)
```

Comment: can you clarify for me .i don't understand it

Comment: Sorry I'm very poor at explaining. Basically I'm using the script to alert me when the word "Shiny" appears however the page is AJAX so it doesn't refresh and despite having the interval for some reason it won't work. The word will appear in the <span id="res"> I think it has something to do with the AJAX.

Comment: so now when you click the arrows does word shiny appear?

Comment: There is a chance of it appearing it doesn't mean the word would appear all the time. Hence why I want the alert. The script works it just needs a word around for the ajax.

Comment: I can provide the HTML/AJAX script. http://pastebin.com/gXeH6eT5 Line 13 has the #res span the below all the HTML is the AJAX script.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
if(window.location.pathname == "/map_final.php") {
   if (/Shiny/i.test (document.getElementById('res').innerHTML)){
     if(confirm("Found it!")) { clearInterval(interval); }
   }
}, 1000);
}
```

By grabbing the specific ID it'll show the updated results;

```
document.getElementById('res').innerHTML)
```